# Duplicated row in the result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I prepared this [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaa3bb/1) in SQL Fiddle. The problem is that the first row is duplicated in the result. How can I show it only once.

Comment: Just add `distinct` [DEMO Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaa3bb/3)

Comment: While having a fiddle prepared is great, it's nice if the query is actually in the question (along with the minimal table definitions and data needed to reproduce the issue) as external links might not reliable and can disappear in the future.

Comment: @jpw: Ok, thanks for this advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think adding `distinct` will give you the correct result, I think the real issue is that you only join the `rides` table on one of its foreign keys (idRide) and not the other (idUser).

Also, mixing implicit joins (in the from clause) with explicit (using the join keyword)  isn't a good idea - it's better to use explicit joins consistently.

I believe the correct query should be:

```
SELECT 
  register.IdRide, 
  users.IdUser, 
  users.Name, 
  (CASE WHEN rides.IdRide IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As IsDriver 
FROM 
   register
JOIN 
   users ON register.IdUser = users.IdUser 
LEFT JOIN 
    rides ON rides.IdUser = users.IdUser
         AND rides.IdRide = register.IdRide
WHERE 
   register.IdRide IN (1) ;
```

With your sample data this would return:

```
| IdRide | IdUser | Name | IsDriver |
|--------|--------|------|----------|
|      1 |      1 |      |        1 |
|      1 |      2 |      |        0 |
|      1 |      3 |      |        0 |
```

Simply adding `distinct` would mark IdUser as IsDriver = 1 which, looking at the data, seems incorrect.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaa3bb/15)

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct

```
SELECT distinct register.IdRide, users.IdUser, users.Name, 
(CASE WHEN rides.IdRide IS NOT NULL THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END
)As IsDriver 
FROM 
   register, 
   users 
        LEFT JOIN rides ON  
        users.IdUser =rides.IdUser
WHERE 
   register.IdRide IN (1) 
   AND register.IdUser = users.IdUser
```

Comment: This will most likely not return correct results as the missing join condition will lead to marking IdUser 2 as driver when it should only be IdUser 1.